# Ajuste de branches locais antes de dar commit

Tags: git, visual-studio

Sou novato no `Git` e preciso fazer um ajuste de forma rápida em meus branches.

Comecei a uma atividade em um branch local errado "X".
Gostaria de migrar as alterações para um branch local "Y" para dar `commit` a partir de "Y" e desfazer as alterações em X.

Como faço para criar um branch Y a partir de X local antes de desfazer as alterações de X?

Estou utilizando Visual Studio 2017 com a extensão do Git para VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você cria uma branch nova:

```
git branch Y
```

Ela já estará com as modificações feitas na branch X. Se quiser verificar se está tudo certo, faz um `git checkout Y` e testa as modificações feitas.

Na branch X para você retornar ao ultimo commit é só utilizar:

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

Lembrando que o `HEAD~1` irá voltar apenas um commit(o ultimo) se você utilizar `HEAD~2` irá voltar a dois commits e assim por diante.

Comment: Bacana... Não sabia que criar Y já traria as alterações de X. Deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Caso a banch Y já estivesse criada era só dar um git merge. Abraço!